# Zero-inflated Poisson with clustered data in R

Tags: poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I am working with ecology count data with a significant amount of zeroes, and I used a multivariate zero-inflated Poisson regression to evaluate the impact of two independent variables on my dependent variable (the count totals). One independent variable is continuous (depth from 3-30) and the other was coded as a dummy variable (soap: yes or no).

However, I realized that my dependent variable values (n=149) violate the requirement of independence because they were collected in a number of different areas (n=33) due to the nature of the experiment. Each of these 33 areas had strong similarities in the values of the independent variables. I need to account for this clustering before I continue with the regression, but how do I do this?